# Projections of totally disconnected spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two metric spaces. If $K$ is a totally disconnected subset of $X\times Y$ must the projections $\pi_{X}(K)$ and $\pi_{Y}(K)$ also be totally disconnected? What if X and Y are assumed to be compact?

Comment: Not sure why the negative vote appeared. Is more information wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even when both are compact.

Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $C=(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})\cap X$. Note that $C$ is totally disconnected and uncountable. Now let $f:C\to[0,1]$ be any bijection and consider

$$K=Gr(f)=\{(x,f(x))\ |\ x\in C\}\subseteq X\times Y$$

It is not hard to see that $K$ is totally disconnected as well, but $\pi_2(K)=[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thank you. It looks like an example of that kind could be precluded by requiring K to be closed?

Comment: @RobertThingum That's an interesting question. Unfortunately I don't know the answer yet.

Comment: @RobertThingum I think this can be fixed by taking $X$ to be the Cantor set, $Y=[0,1]$ and $K=Gr(f)$ for any continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$, which btw exists.